# Upgrade SLIM Framework v2 to SLIM Framework V3 ajax form data

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, twig, slim

I try to upgrade my site code to slim v3 with twig from slim v2 with smarty.
I have tried some things with posting data the only thing is the formdata is not parsed and the page is reloading after submit.

The code i have using on v2 is:

```
$myapp->slim->post('/ajaxlogin', function() use ($myapp) {
$myapp->slim->contentType('application/json');
echo json_encode($myapp->Login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']));
```

});

i have already partly changed it to:

```
$myapp->slim->post('/ajaxlogin', function($req, $res, $args) use ($myapp) {
$myapp->slim->contentType('application/json');
echo json_encode($myapp->Login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']));
```

});

how can i get this to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Have fixed it with the next code:

```
$myapp->slim->post('/ajaxlogin', function($req, $res, $args) use ($myapp) {
$data = $req->getParsedBody();
$result = json_encode($myapp->login($data['username'], $data['password']));
return $res->withStatus(200)->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')->write($result);
```

});